# CJK "undefined" in MikTeX, running normally in TexLive

Tags: fonts, cjk

A file that uses the `CJKutf8` package runs perfectly in OverLeaf (which I assume uses TexLive), however, the same exact file will not compile on my desktop using MiKTeX. I will have

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,brazil]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
   \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}
   あ
   \end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

And I get an error. TeXworks tells me

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'C70/min/b/n' undefined (Font) using 'C70/min/m/n' instead on input line 313.

A friend told me I'm missing the fonts, which is odd considering I used to have the CJK package in use before it suddenly started giving me this error, prompting me to move to OverLeaf.

The question here is, how would I go about to install those fonts back? Or is it just a "MiKTeX needs to update" situation so I can only wait?

Also, important to note I'm using pdfLatex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well fonts are missing in the miktex cjk-package. If you want to resolve that problem you should make a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @UlrikeFischer, I have never filed a bug report, so could you give me some pointers as to how to do it?

Comment: well you could check my list of bug reports: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3Au-fischer+is%3Aclosed